# Como definir proxy no Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, proxy, cucumber, testes-automatizados

Preciso realizar meus testes, mas a rede do meu trabalho utiliza um proxy. 
Qual a melhor maneira para configurar isso dentro do meu env.rb

Abaixo segue meu código  de configuração do arquivo "env.rb"

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "capybara"
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require "rspec"
require 'site_prism'



Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: { accept_insecure_certs: false }

  )


end

Capybara.configure do |config|

  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
  config.app_host = "http://www.google.com"



end

Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.agent.set_proxy("172.16.0.1", 80)

Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 20

Capybara.page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode passar o proxy nos capabilities, ficaria algo assim:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: { accept_insecure_certs: false, proxy: Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(http: "myproxyaddress:8080")}
  )
end
```

Notei que esta utilizando o Chrome, acredito que a capacidade de proxy só funcione para o FireFox.